# Android: Pass the values of a JSONArray to a new activity and have values reference a different object

Tags: android, json

Thanks for your patience, I'm very new to Android development. I want to build a simple app that pulls data from a JSON file. The app's structure is essentially a list of people who have data unique to them (birthdays, quotes), and a list of liked foods that are not unique to them and can be used by other people in the list as well. The liked foods have ingredients that show up when they are tapped on.

I've gotten the initial listview of people functioning but am stuck on how to get their list of liked foods to show up as list items that can be tapped on to show their ingredients. For example, how do I get Amy's liked pizza, which is in an array, to display the ingredient list contained in the "item" object portion of the JSON file.

Current screens and desired outcome for the food ingredients: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji8co.jpg

JSON:

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "name": "Amy",
      "birthday" : "November 20",
      "likes" : [ "pizza", "mac and cheese", "orange juice" ],
      "image" : "pathhere.png"
    },

    {
      "name": "Mark",
      "birthday" : "June 20",
      "likes" : [ "pizza", "orange juice", "apple juice" ],
      "image" : "pathhere.png"
    },

    {
      "name": "Smith",
      "birthday" : "April 10",
      "likes" : [ "cheese" ],
      "image" : "pathhere.png"
    }
  ],
  "item": [
    {
      "name": "pizza",
      "ingredients" : [ "cheese", "dough", "tomato" ],
      "image" : "pathhere.png"
    },

    {
      "name": "mac and cheese",
      "ingredients" : [ "cheese", "pasta" ],
      "image" : "pathhere.png"
    },

    {
      "name": "orange juice",
      "ingredients" : [ "orange" ],
      "image" : "pathhere.png"
    },

    {
      "name": "apple juice",
      "ingredients" : [ "apple" ],
      "image" : "pathhere.png"
    },


    {
      "name": "cheese",
      "image" : "pathhere.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.ListView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var listView: ListView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.person_list)

        val personList = Person.getPersonFromFile("main.json", this)

        val adapter = PersonAdapter(this, personList)
        listView.adapter = adapter

        val context = this
        listView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->

            val selectedPerson = personList[position]

            val detailIntent = PersonDetailActivity.newIntent(context, selectedPerson)

            startActivity(detailIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

Person class

```
import android.content.Context
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject


class Person(
    val name: String,
    val birthday: String,
    val likes: String
)
{

    companion object {

        fun getPersonFromFile(filename: String, context: Context): ArrayList<Person> {
            val personList = ArrayList<Person>()

            try {
                val jsonString = loadJsonFromAsset("main.json", context)
                val json = JSONObject(jsonString)
                val person = json.getJSONArray("person")

                (0 until person.length()).mapTo(personList) {
                    Person(
                        person.getJSONObject(it).getString("name"),
                        person.getJSONObject(it).getString("birthday"),
                        person.getJSONObject(it).getJSONArray("likes").toString()
                    )
                }

            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            return personList
        }


        private fun loadJsonFromAsset(filename: String, context: Context): String? {
            var json: String? = null

            try {
                val inputStream = context.assets.open(filename)
                val size = inputStream.available()
                val buffer = ByteArray(size)
                inputStream.read(buffer)
                inputStream.close()
                json = String(buffer, Charsets.UTF_8)
            } catch (ex: java.io.IOException) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
                return null
            }

            return json
        }
    }
}
```

PersonDetailActivity

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_person_detail.*


class PersonDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var listView: ListView

    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_NAME = "name"
        const val EXTRA_BIRTHDAY = "birthday"
        const val EXTRA_LIKES = "likes"

        fun newIntent(context: Context, person: Person): Intent {
            val detailIntent = Intent(context, PersonDetailActivity::class.java)

            detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, person.name)
            detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_BIRTHDAY, person.birthday)
            detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_LIKES, person.likes)
            return detailIntent

        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_person_detail)

        val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<*>
        val name = intent.extras.getString(EXTRA_NAME)
        val birthday = intent.extras.getString(EXTRA_BIRTHDAY)
        val likes = intent.extras.getString(EXTRA_LIKES)

        person_name.text = name
        person_birthday.text = birthday

        val likesArray = likes.split(",")

        listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.person_likes)

        arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.basic_list_item, R.id.basic_list_text, likesArray)

        listView.adapter = arrayAdapter

    }
}
```

Comment: first of all try to use ` JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);` to convert your json to object, that's make it easy to work with.try use Recycle view but if you ok with listview that's fine. just create costume Adapter and View for your listview then make each food a button to open ingredient in another view(activity or dialog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding a solution as an overview of your issue with the help of simple algo below:

```
//After clicking on spinner item, pass two string to next activity as Json String vai Intent.

//Inside listView.setOnItemClickListener
    String liskesJsonStr = personList[position].getLikes() //Json string for person's like
    String itemsListJson = mainJsonObj.getJsonArray("item").toString() //Json string for all ListItems

    //Create Intent PersonDetailActivity and pass liskesJsonStr and itemsListJson as String.
    //Instead of liskesJsonStr you can pass Person Object directly to PersonDetailActivity and get liskesJsonList there.

//Inside PersonDetailActivity (Assuming I have passed liskesJsonStr instead of Person object)

    //Get person's Like List from liskesJsonStr
    JsonArray personLikedListJson = JsonArray("liskesJsonStr from IntenT") //use personObj.getLikes() if passed person object

    //Creating a hash map with food name as key and the Item object as value
        Create Map<String, JsonObject> mapItem; //class variable
        JsonArray itemListJson = JsonArray("itemsListJson from IntenT")

        loop: 0 to itemListJson.lenght
            mapItem.put(itemJson.getName(), itemListJson[position]);

    //Use personLikedListJson to generate further spinner for Person's liked list so that you can see ingredients for the food after selection.
    //So add create Person's liked food spinner here.....
        //Inside listView.setOnItemClickListener for liked food
            //Get food name: "foodName" using likedFoodObj.get(position) //Where likedFoodObj is the item object of the spinner
            val likedItemJsonObj : JsonObject = mapItem.get(foodName)
            var ingredientList = likedItemJsonObj.getJsonArray(ingredients);

            //Now you as the ingredientList for the selected food item from person's liked food list.
            //use this ingredientList for any further spinner you want to show.
```

Let me know if anything confuse you.

Comment: Thank you for this outline and examples. Your comments were very helpful in explaining and I was able to get the desired result.